# How do I split a string with basic delimiters like "+", "-", "*", and "/" while not using a period as a delimiter as well?

Tags: java, regex, split, delimiter

I need to split a string that is going to be the input of a calculator. I want to split it into two arrays using the split function in java. The first array should only have the numbers of the string (this includes numbers with decimal places). The second should only include the mathematical operators like "+-*/". Currently this is my code:

```
String[] numbers = s.split("[[+-/*]&&[^.]]");
String[] operators = s.split("[^*/+-]");
```

I seem to be able to split the string into the seperate numbers array perfectly fine (even with decimal points), but I can't seem to be able to split the string into the separate operators if there is a decimal point anywhere with the numbers (it works otherwise though).

Ex: I want "9.0/3+2.3" to become {/,+}.

What should I change my regex (for the second line of code) to be to get my desired output? Everything I've tried hasn't worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
String[] numbers = s.split("[[+-/*]&&[^.]]");

ArrayList<String> ops = new ArrayList<String>();
for (String op : s.split("[^*/+-]"))
    if (!op.isEmpty())
        ops.add(op);
String[] operators = ops.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Comment: Doesn't that only apply to the first line? My second line of code seems to be the troubling one...

Comment: That accomplishes what I believe my first line of code already does. As an example, I need a string of "9.0/3" to be split by everything but it's operators. So my second line of code should give me and array with "/" in it.

Comment: @Mike I updated my answer, the operators array was getting filled with empty strings, the answer above should give the result you expected.

Comment: I think that is getting it done. I will need to rearrange my code a little bit to be sure, but a quick test of it certainly looks promising. To your knowledge, is there a prettier way to achieve this by simple regex expression? It seems like we're dodging the best solution by simply ignoring wherever the blank strings show up... Either way, thank you.